# How to read a value in a file with android init.rc (vendor.rc)

Tags: android, file, properties, init

In the android system (pie 9.0)
I want to read a value from a file (/cache/sticky/lcdlive) and write it to a system property (persist.vendor.lcd.live) in a init.vendor.rc

in a exe.sh :

```
lcdfiletmp="cache/sticky/lcdlive"
lcdlivetmp=$(cat "$lcdfiletmp")
setprop persist.vendor.lcd.live $lcdlivetmp
```

, but according to SElinux I don't have a right.

I have tried in vendor.rc:

```
copy /cache/sticky/lcdlive persist.vendor.lcd.live
write persist.vendor.lcd.live /cache/sticky/lcdlive
```

result : persist.vendor.lcd.live = "/cache/sticky/lcdlive" but not the "value" of the file /cache/sticky/lcdlive (which is a number)

```
on early-init
 setprop persist.vendor.lcd.live  0

on property:sys.boot_completed=1
 copy /cache/sticky/lcdlive persist.vendor.lcd.live
```

expected : persist.vendor.lcd.live = value in the file /cache/sticky/lcdlive

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found any way to read a file in init.vendor.rc but I found a solution :

1. create a service with a scripte.sh in init.vendor.rc
2. in the scripte.sh :

> ```
>    lcdfiletmp="cache/sticky/lcdlive"
>     lcdlivetmp=$(cat "$lcdfiletmp")
>     setprop persist.vendor.lcd.live $lcdlivetmp
> ```

3. most important to declare scripte to **system** and chown /cache/sticky/* to **system**. to declare property as vendor_custom
4. add SElinux rules in *.te

it's quite complicated selinux problem, if you have any similar problem feel free to ask here.