# System app to read/write data in vendor partition

Tags: android, selinux

I signed my android app service to a system app to use some services but I have to read/write in a vendor partition to get some data. due to SElinux it's not allowed? Is there a android P interface to communicate?

I can't change my app domain it has to be system_app.

Please help me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I understand android P is critical to separate /vendor and /system partition. It's nearly impossible to write in vendor partition as a system app. 
in using init_vendor.rc, vendor.te and vendor properties you can achieve your goal. check my link :

[How to read a value in a file with android init.rc (vendor.rc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56874397/how-to-read-a-value-in-a-file-with-android-init-rc-vendor-rc)